# roscd returns "bash: reldir: unbound variable"

Tags: ros, bash, setup.sh, setup.bash

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

When going through the tutorial, I get errors with certain ROS (navigation) functions:

```
$ roscd roscpp
bash: reldir: unbound variable
$ rosls roscpp_tutorials
bash: reldir: unbound variable
$ rosed roscpp
bash: 2: unbound variable
```

Any ideas how to resolve this?

---

Info:

```
System: Ubuntu 11.10
Bash: GNU bash, version 4.2.10(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)
Affected tutorial step: http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/NavigatingTheFilesystem
I tried so far: Reinstalling ROS (using apt-get).
What works: rosnode, roscore, rospack, ... (most methods)
What doesn't work: roscd, rosls, rosed
```

Note: During first config as described in the tutorial, I got the following errors:

```
$ source /opt/ros/electric/setup.bash
bash: PYTHONPATH: unbound variable
bash: ROS_MASTER_URI: unbound variable
```

I resolved this by manually defining these variables in ~/.bashrc:

```
$ export PYTHONPATH=$ROS_ROOT/core/roslib/src
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29967/roscd-returns-%22bash:-reldir:-unbound-variable%22/) by [ultinate](https://answers.ros.org/users/2005/ultinate/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2012-03-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks dornhege,

my .bashrc didn't contain `set -u`, but it contained `set -o nounset` instead.

After uncommenting that, all problems mentioned above disappear. I did not change any ROS scripts. Does this mean that ROS scripts are not programmed robustly enough?

In any case, ticket closed.

---

Originally posted by [ultinate](https://answers.ros.org/users/2005/ultinate/) with karma: 16 on 2012-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-03-21**:
-u is short for -o nounset. About the script: I'm not sure, maybe it only works like this in bash. Otherwise it would be worth ticketing.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You .bashrc probably contains `set -u`.

The proper fix would be to change the line in /opt/ros/electric/setup.sh:

```
export PYTHONPATH=${ROS_ROOT}/core/roslib/src:${PYTHONPATH}
```

to

```
export PYTHONPATH=${ROS_ROOT}/core/roslib/src:${PYTHONPATH-}
```

I would say that this is the intended behaviour.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-03-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1